# WinForms TreeView: Treeline hide after a certain level

Tags: winforms, treeview

I would like to know if it is possible to hide treeline in a treeview of winforms after a certain level.

For example to have node1 connected with child node2 with treeline and node2 has a child without treeline

Comment: There's no built-in functionality for this. You can draw the nodes and lines yourself though, see for instance: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/f7e90252-fdfe-4d4c-a94d-17406a960aa6/treeview-ownerdrawall

Comment: I had found something similar but as I can see is the only way. Thank you.